# how can I make a ball bounce inside a Box with CANNON.js and THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I have a `sphere` and `BoxGeometry` in `THREE.js`.
I've setted the standard gravity but my sphere (which is in the center of the box) keep falling down through the box

here are my `CANNON.js` params

**Box**

```
const size = 100
const halfExtents = new CANNON.Vec3(size, size, size)
const boxShape = new CANNON.Box(halfExtents)
const boxBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0, shape: boxShape })
multiBall1.userData.world.addBody(boxBody)
```

**Sphere**

```
const radius = 20;
this.userData.sphereBody = new CANNON.Body({
 mass: 5,
 shape: new CANNON.Sphere(radius),
});
this.userData.sphereBody.position.set(0, 0, 0);
multiBall1.userData.world.addBody(this.userData.sphereBody);
this.position.copy(this.userData.sphereBody.position);
this.quaternion.copy(this.userData.sphereBody.quaternion);
```

I would like to have the ball bounce inside the box. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CANNON.Box is a *solid* box, so it’s not possible to place other objects inside it.

You can construct a *hollow* box using e.g. six planes. Check the code for this demo: https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/container.html

An alternative way to construct a hollow box could be to use six thin box shapes.